# How to write automated code in selenium to user role drop down in Admin portal in OrangeHRM

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"

[image: 2]

My code:

```
 WebElement button1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/i")); 
 button1.click();
 
 
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]")));           

Select user_role_dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div")));
user_role_dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Admin");
```

Comment: You are trying to open a "Select" but the element "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div /div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div" is a div. It's not a select.

You must use .click() and then click on the option. Otherwise please upload your entire code and the page link or a piece of HTML code to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Visually you see a select box but looks like actually it is <div> element. Please can you share HTML code of that part?